# USB Type-C receptacle vs plug

Tags: usb, usb-c

I am learning about USB Type with the help of [this material](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/introduction-to-usb-type-c-which-pins-power-delivery-data-transfer/).In that you can see that two figures Fig1 and Fig2 says  **USB Type-C receptacle and plug**.

1. May I know the difference between  USB Type-C receptacle and plug.

I think receptacle is the type-C connector(I am not sure,please confirm),but no idea about the plug.

Comment: Given that site shows a picture of the plug on the end of the cable and calls it a "port" I wouldn't take anything on there seriously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Receptacle is the socket or connector on the devices.

Plug is the connector on the cables.

You can plug the plug into the receptacle.